# Uniqueness of the solution of simultaneous congruences(chinese remainder theorem )

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The Chinese remainder theorem states that for any $\ n $  integers,which are pairwise coprime  $\ a_1$,$\ a_2 $....$\ a_n$ ,given any integers $\ b_1 $, $\ b_2 $... $\ b_n $ , there exists a unique integer $\ x $ such that it satisfies simultaneously all the congruence equations of the form $\ x $ $\ \equiv $ $\ b_ m $ $\ mod$ $\ a_m $ for  $\ n $ $\ \geq $ $\ m $ $\ \geq $ 1.

The constructive proof for this goes by seeing that for any $\ a_m $ , the product of other integers is also coprime to it. Let for any integer out of the $\ n $ mutually coprime integers  $\ c_m $ = $\ \prod_{k } $ $\ a_k $ ,$\ k $ $\ \neq $ $\ m $ . So as $\ c_m $ is coprime to $\ a_m $ for all $\ m $ , hence for there must exist an integer $\ p _m $ for every $\ m $ such that $\ c_m $ $\ p_m $ $\ \equiv $ 1 $\ mod $ $\ a_m $. 
Now let us consider the integer $\ \sum_{j=1}^n $ $\ b_j$ $\ p_j $ $\ c_j$ . 
This integer as we can see simultaneously satisfies the all the congruence equations .
I would like to know how to prove that this integer is the unique integer that obeys all the congruence equations , while for each $\ c_m $ , the corresponding $\ p_ m $ might not be unique . 
Waiting for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\sum_{j=1}^n b_jp_jc_j$ (the solution you have already constructed). The  $y$ be another solution for the system of the congruences. Then you have 
$$x \equiv y \pmod{a_i} \, \quad \forall \, i$$
But $a_i$'s are pairwise relatively prime, therefore their lcm which will be $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i$ also satisfies
$$x \equiv y \pmod{\prod_{i=1}^n a_i} \, \quad \forall \, i.$$
Thus any solution will be congruent to the one already constructed.

Comment: Then how does that make the solution unique ?

Comment: @OzymandiasAmygdala the uniqueness of the solution is up to the congruence, i.e. in integers there will be infinitely many solutions but all of them will be congruent to each other modulo $\prod_{i=1}^na_i$.